# new content replacing the old one hide and show

Tags: javascript, html, show-hide

I amd working with hiding and showing divs, which have different contents. When i click on a link, i want a div to be shown. But when i click on another link, i want the new content to replace the previous one. Right now, it falls under it instead of replacing it. Any solution?

Javascript

```
function show(){

var links = {
link1: "content1",
link2: "content2",
link3: "content3",
link4: "content4"
};

var id = event.target.id;
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
document.getElementById(links[id]).style.visibility = 'visible';
}

function init(){

 var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
 for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    if (divs[i].className == "div") {
        divs[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
   a[i].onclick = show;
}
}

window.onload = init;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the block of code that hides them all before showing the one you want, every time.

Make this:

```
function hideAll() {
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
     for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        if (divs[i].className == "div") {
            divs[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
}
```

Remove this code from `init()` and replace it with a call to `hideAll()` and add a call to `hideAll()` at the beginning of `show()`.

Comment: the content is supposed to be invisible from the start, therefore having the code in hideAll and calling it will not do so.

Comment: i implemented your hideAll, and kept the code in init. And it worked. when i click on a new link, a new content is shown. however, it doesnt take the place of the previous content, it falls under it. though the previous content gets hidden, it still doesnt take its place

Comment: don't use visibility:visible/hidden, use display:none/block